# MVC5 External Authentication get emails

Tags: email, authentication, external, extract

I have an existing website in MVC4.
Now I am looking forward to upgrade it to MVC5.

I wanna use External Authentication, however, what I want is that when use select any of the External Login option (Except Twitter, I am not going to use it), all I want is to get his/her Name and email address.

I don't wanna store anything in the database with the username or other details associated.

I just need to grab the Name and email address and if it matches with existing email, user will be logged in, otherwise, new account will be created.

It will be great if anyone can help me with this with small tutorial, to read Name, email and other extra details from the user, instead of adding it to the database.

Comment: "It will be great if anyone can help me with this with small tutorial" is not a question. Please [read about how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Asking help and asking question is similar thing I guess.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20379623/2907017) to a similar question on how to extract data from an external provider.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, flag it as such. If you don't have the rep to flag (as is the case) include it as a comment. This is not an answer.

Comment: Actually I don not know to much about how to do that, but I saw this and I saw that it may help. :) Thank you for editing. @Aron Cederholm