# Getting the email from external providers Google and Facebook during account association step in a default MVC5 app using Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity-2

As per this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378043/getting-the-email-from-external-providers-google-and-facebook-during-account-ass/20379623#20379623](http://Getting%20the%20email%20from%20external%20providers%20Google%20and%20Facebook%20during%20account%20association%20step%20in%20a%20default%20MVC5%20app%20using%20Identity%202.0)

I am trying to get the email from an external provider.

This is my code:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
   appId: "X",
   appSecret: "Y");

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "X",
    ClientSecret = "Y"
});
```

The ExternalLoginCallback method in account controller is still as default:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

At this point loginInfo is populated correctly apart from loginInfo.Email which is always null.

No matter the account provider they all authenticate but they all have a null email.

I have create a new MVC5 project from scratch with all nuget packages up to date and the latest VS2013 code.

Answer (score 0):

The default MVC template code does not get an email.

The following edit to startup.configureauth fixes the problem:

```
var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "X",
    AppSecret = "Y"
};

facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Comment: is this still working for you? Since latest changes to facebook api, I cannot get the user email with this code. It is always null exactly as your original question.