# ASP.NET Core Social Login RC1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was using ASP.NET MVC 5 and all was working fine, now I'm working with ASP.NET Core and the social login with Facebook is not getting the email. I have tested with my account and others as well. I'm using:

> "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

This is the code in the Account Controller:

```
// REVIEW: handle case where email not in claims?
var email = loginInfo.ExternalPrincipal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

Startup.cs Example:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = "**********";
                options.AppSecret = "********";

            });
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be specific to **FaceBook** and is documented fairly well in github [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/621) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/620#issuecomment-165464501). Things to ensure you have setup correctly:

1. Ensure app status is "live" https://developers.facebook.com/apps/myappid/review-status/
2. When invoking `app.UseFacebookAuthentication` ensure you add "email" to the scope [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378043/getting-the-email-from-external-providers-google-and-facebook-during-account-ass)
3. If you're still unable, try setting fields explicitly like the example below:

---

```
Options.UserInformationEndpoint = 
   "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,timezone,picture";
```

If you're still not getting what you need, upgrade to RC2.